# Setting up an if...elseif....else in PHP to validate email registration

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Trying to tell the user that they have already registered if the email is a duplicate in the MySQL table. mysqli_connect_errno($link) prints '1062' this is the code for a duplicate primary key. Need some hints. The code above below "Thanks! You're already registered!" no matter if the email address is a duplicate or not.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mailpopper", "MAILpopPASSWORD", "mailpop");


// Ensure the connection is working

if($link === false){
    die("Could not connect to database. Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


// Escape user inputs for security

$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['fname']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lname']);
$org = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['org']);
$email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);

// attempt insert query execution

$sql = "INSERT INTO mail (fname, lname, org, email) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name','$org', '$email_address')";

// HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP

$dupli = mysqli_errno($link);

if($dupli = 1062){

    echo "Thanks! You're already registered!";
}

elseif(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

    echo "Success!";

} else{

    echo "Error: record was not updated. Unable to post. Please try again or contact site owner with error: " . mysqli_error($link);

}

// close connection

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

The code below works, but doesn't give a custom message when the user is already registered. If the user is already registered it says" "Error: record was not updated. Unable to post. Please try again or contact site owner with error: Duplicate entry 'Fagle@bibby.com' for key 'PRIMARY'
'

```
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

    echo "Success!";

    else{

        echo "Error: record was not updated. Unable to post. Please try again or contact site owner with error: " . mysqli_error($link);

    }

    // close connection

    mysqli_close($link);

    ?>
```

Comment: What's the use of checking a *connection* error?

Comment: You're right, I've changed mysqli_connection_error to Mysqli_errno. I was just trying things out to see if I could get it to work, and had switched it for some reason.

Comment: Can people downvoting at least tell me why they are downvoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($dupli = 1062){
```

You are not using a comparison operator.

```
if($dupli === 1062){
```

Your snippets are a little confusing, is the middle one the one you want to use? Are you checking for the errno before executing your sql?

You are using the wrong function to fetch the error, use this one http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php

Tried to fix your code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mail (fname, lname, org, email) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name','$org', '$email_address')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Success!";
}else{
    $error = mysqli_errno($link);
    $errorMessage = "";
    switch ($error) {
        case 1062:
            $errorMessage = "Thanks! You're already registered!";
            break;
        default:
            $errorMessage = "Error: record was not updated. Unable to post. Please try again or contact site owner with error: " . mysqli_error($link);
            break;
    }
    echo $errorMessage;
}
```

- execute the insert statement

  - returns true  or false
- if true, insert succeeded
- if false:

  - fetch the error_code
  - put it in a switch construct to compare it to some codes you knows, define the message accordingly
  - (add messages easily)
  - define a default message for errorcodes you don't want to adress specifically
  - display message

edit:

As mentioned by @Your Common Sense

As your default message in case of an error, you ask the user to tell you about the error.

If the user doesn't want to, you will not get to know about those errors unless you log it yourself. There are different ways to handle errorlogging. You can use i.e. [error_log()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) to write your message into a file or send an email at your adress.

I'll add a simple example to the code:

```
    switch ($error) {
    case 1062:
        $errorMessage = "Thanks! You're already registered!";
        break;
    default:
        $errorMessage = "Error: record was not updated. Unable to post. Please try again later, the site owner has been informed and will fix the problem.";
        error_log('Error occured at date: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' in file: ' . __FILE__ . ' trying to insert into db' . PHP_EOL, 3, 'database_errors.txt');
        break;
}
echo $errorMessage;
```

This way every time an errorcode comes up which you did not specify as a case it will be logged into the "database_errors.txt" (choose the path and names of your logfiles), with information about when and in which file the error occured.

You can of course add other information to the logentries, like write the query into it or whatever you need.

You can also set some directives in the php.ini or via [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to handle errors. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

**Solution:**

> You have to just throw an error, and then let PHP report it according to site-wide settings. So in your else statement you should write trigger_error(mysqli_error($link)); and then let PHP decide whether to log or to display the error.

```
switch ($error) {
    case 1062:
        $errorMessage = "Thanks! You're already registered!";
        break;
    default:
        $errorMessage = "Error: record was not updated. Unable to post. Please try again later, the site owner has been informed and will fix the problem.";
        break;
}
trigger_error(mysqli_error($link));
echo $errorMessage;
```

This way every error will be handled according to the settings (php.ini, ini_set). The switch is used to choose a errormessage to give the user some feedback on what is happening / why the operation failed.

Comment: It works! That's really cool how you did that. Guess I need to study up on when to use if..elseif...else vs. case. The way you did it is really clean.

Comment: Voted for asking a user to report an error to an admin.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Do you mean this part: `$errorMessage = "Error: record was not updated. Unable to post. Please try again or contact site owner with error: " . mysqli_error($link);`? I edited error_logging to the answer

Comment: Logging is less convenient for the development stage debugging. Why not to let PHP decide how to handle an error?

Comment: @YourCommonSense so wait is it bad or good to ask user to report error?

Comment: @Huntario of course it's bad. You have to just throw an error, and then let PHP report it according to site-wide settings. So in your else statement you should write `trigger_error(mysqli_error($link));` and then let PHP decide whether to log or to display the error.